# SQL InitCap that Uppercase some special words

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-function

How can i modify this InitCap function so that it always will uppercase AB when its in the end of the string and has a space before it.

- test Ab <-- should display **AB**
- testab <-- should display ab
- abtest <-- should displat ab

  DELIMITER $$

  ```
  DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `CapitializeFirstCharInEveryWord`$$

  CREATE FUNCTION `CapitializeFirstCharInEveryWord`(x char(100)) RETURNS char(100) CHARSET utf8
  BEGIN
  SET @str='';
  SET @l_str='';
  WHILE x REGEXP ' ' DO
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, ' ', 1) INTO @l_str;
  SELECT SUBSTRING(x, LOCATE(' ', x)+1) INTO x;
  SELECT CONCAT(@str, ' ', CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(@l_str,1,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(@l_str,2)))) INTO @str;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN LTRIM(CONCAT(@str, ' ', CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(x,1,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(x,2)))));
  END$$
  ```

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: Added `mysql` based on those dreaded backticks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to capitalize **last word** in string? You can do it in simple way. Description in comments.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `CapitalizeLastWord`(x char(100)) RETURNS char(100) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
-- detect has x space
SET @space_pos_reverse = LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(x)); 

-- if not return unchanged x
IF @space_pos_reverse = 0 THEN RETURN x; 
END IF;

-- getting last space position
SET @last_space_pos = LENGTH(x)-@space_pos_reverse+1; 

-- split x to 2 parts, 2nd part gettin UPPER
RETURN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(x, 1, @last_space_pos), UPPER(SUBSTRING(x, @last_space_pos+1)) ); 

END$$
```

Comment: Yes i want to capitalize last word if it is AB